# Parameter type covariance in specializations

Tags: php, types, covariance

### tl;dr

What strategies exist to overcome parameter type invariance for specializations, in a language (*PHP*) without support for generics?

<sub>Note: I wish I could say my understanding of type theory/safety/variance/etc., was more complete; I'm no CS major.</sub>

---

### Situation

You've got an abstract class, `Consumer`, that you'd like to extend. `Consumer` declares an abstract method `consume(Argument $argument)` which needs a definition. Shouldn't be a problem.

---

### Problem

Your specialized `Consumer`, called `SpecializedConsumer` has no logical business working with *every* type of `Argument`. Instead, it should accept a `SpecializedArgument` (*and subclasses thereof*). Our method signature changes to `consume(SpecializedArgument $argument)`.

```
abstract class Argument { }

class SpecializedArgument extends Argument { }

abstract class Consumer { 
    abstract public function consume(Argument $argument);
}

class SpecializedConsumer extends Consumer {
    public function consume(SpecializedArgument $argument) {
        // i dun goofed.
    }
}
```

We're breaking [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and causing type safety problems. Poop.

---

### Question

Ok, so this isn't going to work. However, given this situation, what patterns or strategies exist to overcome the type safety problem, and the violation of [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), yet still maintain the type relationship of `SpecializedConsumer` to `Consumer`?

I suppose it's perfectly acceptable that an answer can be distilled down to "*ya dun goofed, back to the drawing board*".

---

### Considerations, Details, & Errata

- Alright, an immediate solution presents itself as "*don't define the `consume()` method in `Consumer`*". Ok, that makes sense, because method declaration is only as good as the signature. Semantically though the absence of `consume()`, even with a unknown parameter list, hurts my brain a bit. Perhaps there is a better way.
- From what I'm reading, few languages support parameter type covariance; PHP is one of them, and is the implementation language here. Further complicating things, I've seen creative "*solutions*" involving [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming); another feature not supported in PHP.
- From Wiki's [Variance (computer science) - Need for covariant argument types?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_(computer_science)#Need_for_covariant_argument_types.3F):

  > This creates problems in some situations, where argument types should be covariant to model real-life requirements. Suppose you have a class representing a person. A person can see the doctor, so this class might have a method virtual void `Person::see(Doctor d)`. Now suppose you want to make a subclass of the `Person` class, `Child`. That is, a `Child` is a Person. One might then like to make a subclass of `Doctor`, `Pediatrician`. If children only visit pediatricians, we would like to enforce that in the type system. However, a naive implementation fails: because a `Child` is a `Person`, `Child::see(d)` must take any `Doctor`, not just a `Pediatrician`.

  The article goes on to say:

  > In this case, the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) could be used to enforce this relationship. Another way to solve the problems, in C++, is using [generic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).

  Again, [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) can be used creatively to solve the problem. I'm exploring the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), as I have a half-baked implementation of it anyway, however most implementations as described in articles leverage method overloading, yet another unsupported feature in PHP.

---

`<too-much-information>`

### Implementation

Due to recent discussion, I'll expand on the specific implementation details I've neglected to include (*as in, I'll probably include way too much*).

> <sub>For brevity, I've excluded method bodies for those which are (*should be*) abundantly clear in their purpose. I've **tried** to keep this brief, but I tend to get wordy. I didn't want to dump a wall of code, so explanations follow/precede code blocks. If you have edit privileges, and want to clean this up, please do. Also, code blocks aren't copy-pasta from a project. If something doesn't make sense, it might not; yell at me for clarification.</sub>

With respect to the original question, hereafter the `Rule` class is the `Consumer` and the `Adapter` class is the `Argument`.

The tree-related classes are comprised as follows:

```
abstract class Rule {
    abstract public function evaluate(Adapter $adapter);
    abstract public function getAdapter(Wrapper $wrapper);
}

abstract class Node {
    protected $rules = [];
    protected $command;
    public function __construct(array $rules, $command) {
        $this->addEachRule($rules);
    }
    public function addRule(Rule $rule) { }
    public function addEachRule(array $rules) { }
    public function setCommand(Command $command) { }
    public function evaluateEachRule(Wrapper $wrapper) {
        // see below
    }
    abstract public function evaluate(Wrapper $wrapper);
}

class InnerNode extends Node {
    protected $nodes = [];
    public function __construct(array $rules, $command, array $nodes) {
        parent::__construct($rules, $command);
        $this->addEachNode($nodes);
    }
    public function addNode(Node $node) { }
    public function addEachNode(array $nodes) { }
    public function evaluateEachNode(Wrapper $wrapper) {
        // see below
    }
    public function evaluate(Wrapper $wrapper) {
        // see below
    }
}

class OuterNode extends Node {
    public function evaluate(Wrapper $wrapper) {
        // see below
    }
}
```

So each `InnerNode` contains `Rule` and `Node` objects, and each `OuterNode` only `Rule` objects. `Node::evaluate()` evaluates each `Rule` (*`Node::evaluateEachRule()`*) to a boolean `true`. If each `Rule` passes, the `Node` has passed and it's `Command` is added to the `Wrapper`, and will descend to children for evaluation (*`OuterNode::evaluateEachNode()`*), or simply return `true`, for `InnerNode` and `OuterNode` objects respectively.

As for `Wrapper`; the `Wrapper` object proxies a `Request` object, and has a collection of `Adapter` objects.
The `Request` object is a representation of the HTTP request. 
The `Adapter` object is a specialized interface (*and maintains specific state*) for specific use with specific `Rule` objects. (*this is where the LSP problems come in*)

The `Command` object is an action (*a neatly packaged callback, really*) which is added to the `Wrapper` object, once all is said and done, the array of `Command` objects will be fired in sequence, passing the `Request` (*among other things*) in.

```
class Request { 
    // all teh codez for HTTP stuffs
}

class Wrapper {
    protected $request;
    protected $commands = [];
    protected $adapters = [];
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function addCommand(Command $command) { }
    public function getEachCommand() { }
    public function adapt(Rule $rule) {
        $type = get_class($rule);
        return isset($this->adapters[$type]) 
            ? $this->adapters[$type]
            : $this->adapters[$type] = $rule->getAdapter($this);
    }
    public function commit(){
        foreach($this->adapters as $adapter) {
            $adapter->commit($this->request);
        }
    }
}

abstract class Adapter {
    protected $wrapper;
    public function __construct(Wrapper $wrapper) {
        $this->wrapper = $wrapper;
    }
    abstract public function commit(Request $request);
}
```

So a given user-land `Rule` accepts the expected user-land `Adapter`. If the `Adapter` needs information about the request, it's routed through `Wrapper`, in order to preserve the integrity of the original `Request`.

As the `Wrapper` aggregates `Adapter` objects, it will pass existing instances to subsequent `Rule` objects, so that the state of an `Adapter` is preserved from one `Rule` to the next. Once **an entire** tree has passed, `Wrapper::commit()` is called, and each of the aggregated `Adapter` objects will apply it's state as necessary against the original `Request`.

We are then left with an array of `Command` objects, and a modified `Request`.

---

**What the hell is the point?**

Well, I didn't want to recreate the prototypical "routing table" common in many PHP frameworks/applications, so instead I went with a "routing tree". By allowing arbitrary rules, you can quickly create and append an `AuthRule` (*for example*) to a `Node`, and no longer is that whole branch accessible without passing the `AuthRule`. In theory (*in my head*) it's like a magical unicorn, preventing code duplication, and enforcing zone/module organization. In practice, I'm confused and scared.

**Why I left this wall of nonsense?**

Well, this is the implementation for which I need to fix the LSP problem. Each `Rule` corresponds to an `Adapter`, and that ain't good. I want to preserve the relationship between each `Rule`, as to ensure type safety when constructing the tree, etc., however I can't declare the key method (*`evaluate()`*) in the abstract `Rule`, as the signature changes for subtypes.

On another note, I'm working on sorting out the `Adapter` creation/management scheme; whether it is the responsibility of the `Rule` to create it, etc.

`</too-much-information>`

Comment: I don't have time to go in-depth at the moment, but this is IMHO an important reason why it's better to prefer [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Your problem arises because you're trying to extend an abstract in the first place. My initial suggestion is to use interfaces instead of abstract classes, typehint the interfaces in your method signatures and compose functionality as necessary via the constructors.

Comment: @Dan i find myself asking this question you voiced years ago. do you recall which path you took? have your thoughts changed since then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To properly answer this question, we must really take a step back and look at the problem you're trying to solve in a more general manner (and your question was already pretty general).

### The Real Problem

The real problem is that you're trying to use inheritance to solve a problem of business logic. That's never going to work because of LSP violations and -more importantly- tight coupling your business logic to the application's structure.

So inheritance is out as a method to solve this problem (for the above, and the reasons you stated in the question). Fortunately, there are a number of compositional patterns that we can use.

Now, considering how generic your question is, it's going to be very hard to identify a solid solution to your problem. So let's go over a few patterns and see how they can solve this problem.

### Strategy

The [Strategy Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) is the first that came to my mind when I first read the question. Basically, it separates the implementation details from the execution details. It allows for a number of different "strategies" to exist, and the caller would determine which to load for the particular problem.

The downside here is that the caller must know about the strategies in order to pick the correct one. But it also allows for a cleaner distinction between the different strategies, so it's a decent choice...

### Command

The [Command Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) would also decouple the implementation just like Strategy would. The main difference is that in Strategy, the caller is the one that chooses the consumer. In Command, it's someone else (a factory or dispatcher perhaps)...

Each "Specialized Consumer" would implement only the logic for a specific type of problem. Then *someone else* would make the appropriate choice.

### Chain Of Responsibility

The next pattern that may be applicable is the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility). This is similar to the strategy pattern discussed above, except that instead of the consumer deciding which is called, each one of the strategies is called in sequence until one handles the request. So, in your example, you would take the more generic argument, but check if it's the specific one. If it is, handle the request. Otherwise, let the next one give it a try...

### Bridge

A [Bridge Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge) may be appropriate here as well. This is in some sense similar to the Strategy pattern, but it's different in that a bridge implementation would pick the strategy at construction time, instead of at run time. So then you would build a different "consumer" for each implementation, with the details composed inside as dependencies.

### Visitor Pattern

You mentioned the [Visitor Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) in your question, so I'd figure I'd mention it here. I'm not really sure it's appropriate in this context, because a visitor is really similar to a strategy pattern that's designed to traverse a structure. If you don't have a data structure to traverse, then the visitor pattern will be distilled to look fairly similar to a strategy pattern. I say fairly, because the direction of control is different, but the end relationship is pretty much the same.

### Other Patterns

In the end, it really depends on the concrete problem that you're trying to solve. If you're trying to handle HTTP requests, where each "Consumer" handles a different request type (XML vs HTML vs JSON etc), the best choice will likely be very different than if you're trying to handle finding the geometric area of a polygon. Sure, you *could* use the same pattern for both, but they are not really the same problem.

With that said, the problem *could* also be solved with a [Mediator Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator) (in the case where multiple "Consumers" need a chance to process data), a [State Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) (in the case where the "Consumer" will depend on past consumed data) or even an [Adapter Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) (in the case where you're abstracting a different sub-system in the specialized consumer)...

In short, it's a difficult problem to answer, because there are so many solutions that it's hard to say which is correct...

Answer (score 5):

The only one known to me is DIY strategy: accept simple `Argument` in function definition and immediately check if it is specialized enough:

```
class SpecializedConsumer extends Consumer {
    public function consume(Argument $argument) {
        if(!($argument instanceof SpecializedArgument)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Argument was not specialized.');
        }
        // move on
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dev-null-dweller. Certainly a consideration I've made (*neglected to amend that*); it may be the direction I'll have to take. I've sort of adopted a practice of "*...despite PHP being dynamically typed, and requiring no formal parameter typing in function declarations, if a reasonable IDE lexer/parser can follow along with me, then type safety has been somewhat implemented.*" It may sound silly, but it saves me from introducing vagueness. Conditional checking as pseudo-down-casting, which again may have to work. (*I hate having to prepend "pseudo" to everything when talking PHP*)

Comment: This violates LSP as well as `Consumer::consume` method didn't throw the InvalidArgumentException. You just walked around php's checks to let you do this.