# Abstract class or interface where declaration method signature allows type hinting of child classes

Tags: php, design-patterns

TLDR:  The add method with a child object argument doesn't match the implementation which calls the parent class.  Is there a way around this?

Unless there is a better way, my plan was to create an interface for Collections, like so:

```
interface Collection {
   public function add( ValueObjects $obj ) : bool;
}

abstract class ValueObjects {}

class User extends ValueObjects {
}
```

I am then implementing the Collection interface on concrete collection of User value objects.

```
class UserCollection implements Collection {
  public function add( User $user ) : bool 
  {
     return true;
  }
}
```

This obviously throws an error that `Declaration should be compatible with Collection`.  Is there a way to achieve the same result to allow children objects in the signature?  I tried with abstract classes and no result.

It would be even better if I didn't have to extend the abstract ValueObjects class.

Thanks for sharing your knowledge SO community.

PS... reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244284/php-type-hint-interface-in-abstract-methods-and-type-hint-interfaces-child-clas) , decorator and composition patterns.  I either missed it or my question is a little different.

Comment: Here's why you don't want to do this, even if it was possible: you get a `Collection` object somewhere, and you want to call the `add` method. The interface says that you accept any `ValueObjects`. So you do. But instead you got a `UserCollection`, which accept only a sub type of it. `Collection` contract is broken, you cannot pass any `ValueObjects`, just `User`. You can't trust `Collection`, the interface is meaningless; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: What is the point of the `abstract ValueObjects` class? Marker interfaces should be interfaces; boilerplate and actual extensions belong in abstractions, like an `add` that's useful except when overridden by an implementing compositor.

Comment: Thank you @Federkun that makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by marker interfaces?  @JaredFarrish  Appreciate you explaining

Comment: A marker interface marks a class as being of type without implementing detail. Say you wanted only side-effect free values of known type to be given to a method. This is too varied to guess, and is beyond abstract. Mark the class using `class User implements Valuable` with `interface Valuable {}`, which has no concrete expression of what that means, only that it passes identity checks. It can't be proven with an interface a class doesn't implement side-effects, so force a develop to "contract" that it does by marking it as so.

Comment: Traits and abstract classes are meant to define constructs that are shared, behavioral in the former and conceptual in that latter, which means property and method signatures. They are partial implementations that require type, in other words.

Comment: In reality, I think a `ValueObject` interface isn't rudimentary; it's abstract for a definition of use. I would say a marker of `Boxed` or `Transportable` conveys the meaning it's transitory in nature. A "value object" is a construct, not really an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue for something along these lines. Note how I'm *extending* core concepts of objectively collecting, while behaving as a self-validating subject. Then I *compose* these various constructs into a knowable, concrete composite.

```
interface Transportable {};
interface User {};
interface Collected
{
    public function isValid($item): bool;

    // Contract, add is deterministic, require no return
    public function add(Transportable $item): void;
}

trait SanityChecked
{
    public function isValid($item): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}

abstract class Collector implements Collected
{
    use SanityChecked;

    private $items = [];

    public function add(Transportable $item): void
    {
        if ($this->isValid($item) && $this->items[] = $item) {
            return;
        }

        throw new Exception('This is the not the droid we were looking for.');
    }
}

class Users extends Collector
{
    public function isValid($test): bool
    {
        return $test instanceof User;
    }
}
```

Which can be mocked as:

```
$users = new Users();

$users->add(new class() implements Transportable, User {});

echo 'Added first!'.PHP_EOL;

$users->add(new class() implements User {}); // Sorry, error.

echo 'Added second!'.PHP_EOL;
```

https://3v4l.org/O2qfJ

Another way of looking at it is to further extend behavior of trait:

```
trait ValidatesAsUser
{
    public function isValid(Transportable $user): bool
    {
        return $user instanceof User;
    }
}

class PortalUsers extends Collector
{
    use ValidatesAsUser;
}

class ContentEditors extends PortalUsers {}

class Authors extends ContentEditors {}

class AuthorsWithPublishedStoriesByRating extends Authors {}
```

I think the last part about projections is particularly interesting.

Comment: Possibly even more interesting would be `trait ValidatesContentEditor` with `class ContentEditors extends Users` and the validity check in our new trait is superclassed with `return $test instanceof ContentEditor && parent::isValid($item);`. I suspect, however, a useful implementation would have `ContentEditor` extend `User` concrete class with overrides, however further role chaining may make use of this behavior, for instance if all `ContentEditor`s are also `PortalUser`s.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this.  I've been struggling with composition over inheritance for a while now, so I really do appreciate helping me get over that block.  :)

Comment: I try to imagine my box of things as having devices and machines, like in a real factory (not the software construct). Then who is the craftsman standing at the work station? You're having a discussion. You have to imagine, define and understand what parts you put together, and for the cast of characters (users, roles, etc.) that exist. This is composition. Creating a greater whole out of lesser parts (a paper is a composition of sentences, for instance).

Comment: Also, I realized, this is class composition, as opposed to object composition. Object composition is where you modularize the first-class types. Think of "multi-speed electric driveshaft seven-chuck screwdriver" versus "drill". One is a specification, the other is a tool. Object composition is about tooling your domain parts so they're single-purpose.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "No" because of the lack of generic classes in PHP.

To work around this, you should keep using the abstract type (here `ValueObjects`) in the implement class and then check for the actual type by yourself.

```
class UserCollection implements Collection {
  public function add( ValueObjects $obj ) : bool 
  {
     if (!($obj instanceof User)) {
          throw new RuntimeException('...');
     }

     /** @var User $obj */
     // The above comment make your IDE know the $obj is a `User` instance

     // your actual logic
     return true;
  }
}
```

One small note, you do not need to cast the `$obj` object from `ValueObjects` to `User` in PHP. A phpDoc inline `@var` comment line as in the code above only tell the IDE that the `$obj` is a `User` instance and support auto-completing for `User` methods. Without it, the PHP script still run.

Comment: Including the `bool` instead of `void` is meaningless and extrapolates context where there is none: If it fails to add and returns false, what then? An exception is more meaningful, which obviates the return signature.

Comment: I agree with you. The return statement is in the original code of OP and I only keep it.